# Jasmine, Angular - How to test a property assertion?

Tags: angular, testing, input, jasmine

Jasmine - Angular

This is a part of the component, that is being tested (TestingThisComppnent ):

```
import { ThatComponent } from '.../shared/components';

export class TestingThisComppnent {
  (...)

  @ViewChild('child', { static: true })
  public map: GoogleMapComponent;

  public ngOnInit(): void { 
    (...)
    this.map.infoWindowComponent = ThatComponent;
  }
}
```

GoogleMapComponent:

```
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {
 (...)
  @Input()
  public infoWindowComponent: any;
 (...)
}
```

How can I test this line? -

```
this.map.infoWindowComponent = WorkItemInfoWindowComponent;
```

We are not using ComponentFixture in the project, but creating a component class by 'new' -

```
    subject = new WorkItemLocationTabComponent(
      firstSpy,
      secondSpy,
      thirdSpy,
      fourthSpy
    );
```

I've tried by creating a Spy -

```
infoWindowComponentSpy = spyOnProperty(subject.map, 'infoWindowComponent');
```

but because (I guess) 'infoWindowComponent' is an @Input(), I'm getting an error, that the property 'does not have access type get', so I've added get() and set() -

```
    Object.defineProperty(subject.map, 'infoWindowComponent', {
      get: function () {
          return this.value;
      },
      set: function (val) {
        this.value = val;
        return this.value;
      },
    });
```

But still, the test doesn't work, because log of subject.map.infoWindowComponent always returns 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using `TestBed` and just doing

```
subject = new WorkItemLocationTabComponent(
      firstSpy,
      secondSpy,
      thirdSpy,
      fourthSpy
    );
```

`ViewChild` will never be able to populate the `map` variable.

Try doing this:

```
it('sets the infoWindowComponent', () => {
  (subject.map as any) = { infoWindowComponent: null }
  subject.ngOnInit();
  expect((subject.map as any).infoWindowComponent).not.toBeNull();
});
```